# Proof of convergence test - (Apostol, Calculus, 10.16 #15)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm self-studying from Apostol, Calculus, Volume I and am having trouble with the following exercise (Section 10.16, #15, p. 402):

> Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequences with $a_n > 0$ and $b_n > 0$ for all $n \geq N$, and let $c_n = b_n - \frac{b_{n+1} a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.  Prove that:
>
> (a) If there is a positive constant $r$ such that $c_n \geq r > 0$ for all $n \geq N$, then $\sum a_n$ converges.  [Hint: Show that $\sum_{k=N}^n a_k \leq \frac{a_N b_N}{r}$.]
>
> (b)If $c_n \leq 0$ for $n \geq N$ and if $\sum 1/b_n$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ diverges.
> [Hint: show that $\sum a_n$ dominates $\sum 1/b_n$.]

For part (a) I cannot seem to figure out how to arrive at the hint, nor how to use it.

I looked at a simple test case of $b_n = 1$, so we arrive at
$$ c_n = 1 - \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq r > 0 \qquad \forall \; n \geq N$$
Hence, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1 - r$, and hence $ < 1$.  Therefore, $\sum a_n$ converges.

So, from the simple case we see a bit of what's going on.  My inclination is then to do a proof by contradiction… Suppose the limit is $\geq 1$ and get a contradiction (which should result since $b_n$ will need to go to $0$, contradicting the positivity of $b_n - b_{n+1} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.  Obviously, this doesn't make any use of the hint, though, so maybe is the wrong idea.  I do think this contradiction will work, but it seems Apostol envisioned a more direct approach that I do not see.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115146/trying-to-prove-convergence-test).

Comment: thanks, didn't find that when I searched.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is it most appropriate to delete this question then?

Comment: If it seems fine to you, go ahead.

Comment: In all fairness, your title is a better fit, and I'll use it so people can find the question.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I can't seem to figure out how to delete it anyway.  Maybe there is a reputation threshold or some such. Probably it will get closed as duplicate on its own.  Or linger and help people find it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Also, there's a typo in my title (which you accurately copied).  It's Problem #15, not problem #1.

Comment: Fixed. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @amy_t: do you want me to delete this question?